# How to add animation to photos changing every 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, animation

The pictures change themselves every 3 seconds.
I would like to add simple animation to the photo during the change.
Preferably in vaniilla js.

```
let index = 1;
const changeImg = () => {
  index++;
  img.setAttribute('src', `img/img${index}.png`);

  if (index === 3) {
    index = 0;
  }
};
setInterval(changeImg, 3000);
```

Comment: You could achieve this with 2 `img` elements and a CSS animation. E.g. `classList.add('animation')` and then `.classList.remove('animation')`. The animation could be based on  `opacity` and then you swap the img src after the animation so you can re-do the animation with the next img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use something like animate.css, or create your own animation class you could do it like this:

(Im assuming you're getting the image by a query selector/getElementById)

```
let index = 1;
const changeImg = () => {
  index++;
  img.classList.add('animate__animated');
  img.classList.add('animate__bounce');

  setTimeout(() => {
    img.setAttribute('src', `img/img${index}.png`);

    img.classList.remove('animate__animated');
    img.classList.remove('animate__bounce');
  }, 300); // This delay is assuming the animation duration is 300ms, you need to change this to the length of the animation



  if (index === 3) {
    index = 0;
  }
};
setInterval(changeImg, 3000);
```

Comment: could you write css styles please? :(

Comment: Those are css classes from [animate.css](https://animate.style/). Take a look at that package as it is a really powerful css animations package. Also please mark my answer as useful :)

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested an example in vanilla JavaScript (no libraries), here you go.

```js
(function slideShow() {
  let imgs = [
    "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300"
  ];

  let index = 0;
  const frontImg = document.getElementById("slideshow__img--front");
  const backImg = document.getElementById("slideshow__img--back");
  frontImg.src = imgs[index];

  const changeSlideShowImg = () => {
    const currImgSrc = imgs[index];
    index++;
    if (index >= imgs.length) index = 0;
    const newImgSrc = imgs[index];

    backImg.src = newImgSrc;
    frontImg.classList.add("slideshow__img--fadeout");

    setTimeout(() => {
      frontImg.src = newImgSrc;
      frontImg.classList.remove("slideshow__img--fadeout");
    }, 500);
  };

  setInterval(changeSlideShowImg, 3000);
})()
```

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.slideshow__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

#slideshow__img--front {
  z-index: 2;
}

.slideshow__img.slideshow__img--fadeout {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <img id="slideshow__img--front" class="slideshow__img" />
  <img id="slideshow__img--back" class="slideshow__img" />
</div>
```